# Decreasing runtime in C++

Tags: c++, runtime

How can I decrease the runtime of this code?

It takes more than 2 seconds for large input. How to solve this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    long long int test_cases, num, ans, x, pair, y, z;
    cin >> test_cases;
    for(x=1; x<=test_cases; x++){
        pair = 0;
        cin >> num;
        for(y=1; y<=num; y++){
            for(z=1; z<=num; z++){
                ans = y*y+z*z+gcd(y, z)*gcd(y, z)+lcm(y, z)*lcm(y, z);
                if (ans==num){
                    pair = pair+1;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << pair << endl;
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to run the loops all the way to `num`. It's clear that, once `y*y >= num` or `z*z >= num`, it's pointless to check larger numbers. That would cut the running time from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)`, since you would have two nested loops each running `sqrt(n)` iterations.

Comment: Also, don't compute `gcd` and `lcm` twice, that will likely further halve your runtime.

Comment: Also, you could do `for (z=y; ...)`. The formula is symmetrical - if `(a, b)` pair is a hit, then so would be `(b, a)` pair; you don't need to test both.

Comment: If this code works, and you just want to optimize it, then you should ask on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: We can derive tighter bounds. Assuming without loss of generality that `y <= z`, then `gcd(y, z)` is in the range `[1, y]`, and `lcm(y, z)` is in the range `[z, y*z]`. Then `ans` is in the range `[y^2+2*z^2+1, 2*y^2+z^2+y^2*z^2]`. For `n` to fall into this range, it must be that `z^2 >= (n-2*y^2)/(1+y^2)` and `z^2 <= (n-y^2-1)/2`. This would help shorten the inner loop further.

Comment: @PaulSanders The compiler (gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/11nrWzMxc) is smart enough to recognize `gcd` and `lcm` are pure functions and only call them once. Look at lines 63 and 86. It squares the result from `gcd` and `lcm`. It doesn't (and can't due to risk of overflow) use that `lcm(y, z) == y * z / gcd(y, z)` and `lvm(y, z) * lcm(y, z) == (y * y) * (z * z) / (gcd(y, z)^2)`. So overall one can optimize the computation: `y2 = y * y; z2 = z * z; g2 = gcd(y, z); g2 *= g2; l2 = y2 * z2 / g2; ans = y2 + z2 + g2 + l2;` Note: y2 can be compute in the outer loop but again the compiler should see that.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Clever gcc.  Nevertheless, I would cache the duplicate computations in local variables.

Comment: (Because I wouldn't want to rely on that).